# How to properly handle IOException with NFCA.transceive?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, try-catch, nfc

I'm a beginner with Android developement and I'm trying to configure a "pass-through" mode for NFC. Basically I2C writes something on an NFC TAG, Mobile Phone picks it up, new data is written by I2C and so on. I kind of struggle with the time the tag is written: Meanwhile, the phone gets an "NAK" and throws back an IOException since transceive fails. How can I properly handle it? I tried with "thread.millis" to wait till I2C is done, but this solution looks pretty crappy and only works with my arduino and phone.

```
while (Schleife < 1000) {
                                try {
                                   answer = ultralight.transceive(command); //This one throws an IOException if the data is not ready yet                        
                                   Schleife = Schleife + 1;
                                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                                  //Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", ioe.toString());
                                }
}
```

I want the program to re execute the process. One thing I tried was to include the catch statement into the while-loop, but it took forever sometimes to rerun the while loop.

I'm thankful for every answer.

Kind regards

Comment: It sounds like you have some NFC chip that you are trying to get it to talk to a mobile phone. Give details on the NFC chip hardware you are using and the code for how you are controlling that chip. I think you misunderstand how NFC works. There are 3 main modes NFC chips can work in reader/writer, host card emulation and peer to peer. It sounds like you are trying to use to reader/writer modes to talk to each other, this won't work. You need a reader/writer to talk to a real card (or NFC chip in host card emulation mode) or both in peer to peer mode (but that has been removed in Android 10)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I'm using the NXP NFC NTag NT3H1101/NT3H120. It supports something called "pass-through"-mode, basically I2C writes on NTAG, Mobile Phone reads it, I2C writes again and so on, everything happens in a quick moment. While the phone reads the SRAM, it immediatly tries to read again, which does not work since the SRAM is being written by I2C. Therefore a "NAK" is returned by the NFC Chip which triggers an IOException I want to handle.

Comment: OK now we know which chip you are using it is easier to understand that you have a dual interface NFC card chip (So it is a reader/writer to NFC card mode) but the chip has a special mode to bypass the normal EEPROM). The question is what is the `command` you are trying to transceive? At the transceive level a NAK is valid transceive response and should not be an IO Exception (data was successfully sent and received).You also might want to look at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/nfc/tech/BasicTagTechnology.java

Comment: I'm trying to transceive the command "Fast_Read" which reads 64 bytes of the sram in one command. It looks like this:
Command[0] = 0xA0; [1] = 0xF0, [2] = 0xFF. Its a simple transceive command.

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the datasheet for the chip is that you are looping around transceiving the wrong command.

> After a READ or FAST_READ command involving the terminator page of the SRAM, bit SRAM_RF_READY and bit RF_LOCKED are automatically reset to 0b allowing the I2C interface to further write data into the SRAM buffer.To signal to the host that further data is ready to be written, the following mechanisms are in place:•The NFC interface polls/reads the bit SRAM_RF_READY from NS_REG (see Table14) to know if new data has been written by the I2C interface in the SRAM

You loop should be read E8h block and checking the to see if the SRAM is ready to be read by the RF connection, then read 64 bytes with fast read when the right bits are set in byte 0

This is how the chip implements a flow control mechanism between the I2C interface and the RF interface to prevent errors.

**update**
Ok the implementation sheet shows how to do it without flow control.

For the question how to handle a NACK, first you need to check for it
Below is how I check for a NACK

```java
if ((answer != null) && (answer.length == 1) && ((answer[0] & 0x00A) != 0x00A)) {
         // Got NACK
        Log.e("Nack", Schleife); //added to identify iteration.

}
```

It would be helpful to also log the iteration number of any IOException

I'm thinking that the NACK and IO exception are on different iterations.
As a proper NACK is not an IO Exception.

Also Android code the anticollision under the hood, so the only thing you can try when receiving the NACK is `close` and `connect` again.

or

A low level transeive to "0x95 0x70 (UID bytes)" be correct
(taken from https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-3.18/net/nfc/digital_technology.c#349 )
"0x95 0x70" I think is the correct Anti-collison command for the card type.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I've already tried this method, however doing so would require a "SectorSelect", since the RF_READY_BIT is located there and doing a SectorSelect is pretty slow. I want to transmit data as fast as possible and including a SectorSelect would slow down the proccess. I want to try this:
"The NFC side in the meanwhile can check if data is already available in the SRAM via
polling on the bit “SRAM_RF_READY” or it simply tries reading the memory and in case
it gets a NACK it executes again the anti-collision to the tag and tries again."

Comment: Which can be found by https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN11579.pdf (page 6), but I simply don't know how to handle a NACK or IOException.